# How to compare inputs and check if a number is negative, positive or zero

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I wrote the initial code for this problem but I want to be able to take `-1` as an input. Right now it takes only one input `1` or `-` and then shows the result.

I'm a novice when it comes to assembly language and `emu8086` so it would really help me out if someone could help me to solve this problem.

**Here's the code so far:**

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db 0ah,0dh,'negative$'
msg1 db 0ah,0dh,'positive$'
msg2 db 0ah,0dh, 'zero$'
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    mov bl,al

    mov cl,30h


    cmp bl,cl
    jl negative
    je zero
    jg positive


    negative:
    lea dx,msg
    mov ah,9
    int 21h 
    jmp END

    zero:
    lea dx,msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp END

    positive:
    lea dx,msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h


    END: 
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
    main endp
end main
```

Comment: keep in mind the `int 21h, ah=1` does return "characters" (or zero when extended scan code will be returned upon next call), not integers, so entering "-1" as user, when handled by this service, will need two calls, and values 45 (ASCII encoding for '-') and 49 (ASCII encoding for '1') will be returned. There are no DOS or BIOS services in PC to input integers, so you are on the correct path, but you must write your own code to handle multi-character input, and convert it from string into number (or you can use some library, not sure what emu8086 has in offer by default).

Comment: (as now you are only printing negative/zero/positive, you don't even need to convert the string into integer, your current code is quite OK, it just needs some way to know how many chars it should read (if only single digit input values are allowed, then you need to read one or two chars, depending if "-" was used... also it would be nice then to support "+", i.e. "+4" as valid input))

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a digit string optionally prefixed with a `-`, you should check for a the optional `-` instead of checking if the ASCII code is > or < than `30h`.  If you only support single-digit numbers, then seeing a `-` means you need to read exactly 1 more byte.